# Dragging from NSBrowser and use bindings?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsbrowser

I've implemented a browser that shares NSTreeController with NSOutlineView so I can easily switch between them and keep the states in sync. Implementing drag support for NSOutlineView is simple, but it appears that NSBrowser cannot support dragging while using bindings. Has anyone been able to support dragging from NSBrowser while also using bindings?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating custom subclasses of `NSBrowser`, `NSMatrix`, and `NSBrowserCell`. I had to force `NSBrowser` to use `NSRadioModeMatrix` mode (single cell) by setting this mode in `NSBrowser` subclass `-mouseDown` method because it was constantly being reset.

In the `NSBrowserCell` subclass, I implemented `trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:` by simply having superclass do it's thing, but returned `NO` so tracking would occur, which allowed `mouseDragged:` to be called in my `NSMatrix` subclass. In `mouseDragged:` I then did all the stuff to get the mouse location, construct a mouse image, and used `[self dragImage:at:offset:pasteboard:source:slideBack:]`.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it worked. It only works when there is a single selection allowed in `NSBrowser`.